# State update in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, routes, use-effect

Passing an object link message from another page to another via Link.

```
<Link
    to={{
      pathname: '/study-desk',
      state: {
        messageFromLibrary: 'notesPane',
      },
    }}
>
```

Then receiving and using it to setState on another page.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof (props.location.state) !== 'undefined' || props.location.state != null) {
      const { messageFromLibrary } = props.location.state;
      setPane(messageFromLibrary);
    } else {
      // error handling, if message undefined
      setPane('default');
    }
}, []);
```

Getting the error message: This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the `componentWillUnmount` method.. Can see that using: `return () =>` in the `useEffect` hook might have a use here but I cant figure out how it should be done. Any ideas?

Comment: The above code seems to be correct. Are you sure the error is originating in the code you mentioned

Comment: Yes looks like it is it, if I remove the setPane() then it dissapears. Error comes only first time I go to the page. const [pane, setPane] = useState('default'); is the state the message changes from beginning that renders a component and another component when changed with the message. @ShubhamKhatri

Comment: Probably you need your if-else condition to be `if (typeof (props.location.state) !== 'undefined' && props.location.state != null) {` However I doubt that it would affect anything. If possible can you make a reproducible demo

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri This is how the component is rendered from state `switch (pane) {
    case 'read':
      desk = (
        <MyComponent/>
      );
      break;
    case 'notes':
      desk = (
        <MyComponent2/> return({desk})`

Comment: Do you have any effect which could be relying on `pane` change?

Comment: @LiJonas Yes a bit closer now, seems like the error exist only with the specific component. This page/component includes also a pdf reader child element created with `import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf';` it takes a prop that locates the pdf file={myPdFile} if I comment it out and the pdf is not rendered the error goes away. Any ideas how to structure such setup and handle the error, might be this?

Comment: @PatrikRikama-Hinnenberg would it be possible to see that component or at least relevant code from it?

Comment: @LiJonas Here is the component where the simple switch case changes the layout, the messageFromLibrary in useEffect changes the default layout. [https://pastebin.com/Ah9qzyuT] and this is the child [https://pastebin.com/46UbLsUQ]. If I comment out the file={test2} prop from the <Document > that is provided by react-pdf the error disappears. error: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.

Comment: Not that pretty solution, I see now that I "unnecessary" re-render the <ImageBook> Thought it was smart earlier :) That should not be the error though..

Comment: The PasteBin link will only work if you copy and remove the [ ].